# TraceSource across threads doesn't work?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, system.diagnostics

I think I've lost my mind guys.. According to MSDN, TraceSource is thread safe. So I have a simple console app. In it, I declare;

```
private static readonly TraceSource ActiveTraceSource = new TraceSource("Test");
```

In my app.config, I have;

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="consoleListener" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"/>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Inside my main(), I do something like;

```
ActiveTraceSource.TraceInformation("Hi!");
```

Works fantastic, I have Hi! on my console. Then I do this;

```
new Thread(DoWork).Start();
```

Inside DoWork, I do the same thing;

```
ActiveTraceSource.TraceInformation("Hi!");
```

Should work, but I don't get the second 'Hi!'.. Setting a breakpoint shows me that DoWork has an instance of ActiveTraceSource, and there is a listener in the collection, but nothing in the console.

Is this a bug in the console listener? Am I missing something?

Comment: I added a TextWriterListener to see if it's just the console -- same effect, it doesn't write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid is as stupid does.. when using a tracesource, really helps to include the  part of the config..

Answer (score 3):

I used following config.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="Test" switchValue="All">
        <listeners>
          <add name="consoleListener" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>    
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Test Code:

```
class Program
        {
        private static readonly TraceSource ActiveTraceSource = new TraceSource("Test"); 
        static void Main(string[] args)
            {

            ActiveTraceSource.TraceInformation("Hi");
            Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Test));
            th.Start();
            Console.ReadLine();
            }

        static void Test()
            {
            ActiveTraceSource.TraceInformation("Hi");
            }
        }
```

It works for me in thread as well.